# Error in date setting code in java spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, java-time

I would like to create a @Configuration with the object to format my dates in my API developed in Java (Spring boot), but it is returning some errors

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDateTimeSerializer'
Cannot resolve symbol 'LocalDateTimeSerializer'
'addSerializer(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer<?>)' in 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule' cannot be applied to '(LocalDateTimeSerializer)'
```

here the code

```
package com.api.parking_control.configs;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Configuration
public class DateConfig {

    public static  final String DATETIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    public static LocalDateTimeSerializer LOCAL_DATETIME_SERIALIZER = new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATETIME_FORMAT));


    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        module.addSerializer(LOCAL_DATETIME_SERIALIZER);
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Comment: While I don’t know why you are getting those errors, I do know that enclosing `Z` in single quotes in the format pattern string is wrong. If you are receiving JSON with a trailing `Z` in the datetimes, deserialize them into `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`. The default deserializers should work.

Comment: Can you confirm the java version and spring boot version you are using in this app ?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to be using here. That class cannot represent a moment, a point on the timeline. Search *Stack Overflow* and *The Java Tutorials* by Oracle Corp to learn more.